# How to install ubuntu from another version of ubuntu?

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu

Sorry, this is probably a duplicate but i cant seem to find exactly what im looking for. I have lubuntu installed on my computer right now, and would like to switch it to just regular ubuntu. I made a bootable usb of ubuntu 14.0.4 using startup disk creator, and assumed i would install it by launching grub during the boot process, although when i do that i don't see an option to boot from the usb.. The options i get are

"*Ubuntu (which just launches my desktop)

Advanced options for Ubuntu

Memory test (memtest86+)

Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200"

Am i doing something wrong? Missing a step? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To boot from a USB and then launch a live session of Ubuntu from your USB, you have to go into your BIOS and change your settings to first boot from USB  (Or you can select USB to boot from by entering the one-time boot selection). This will boot from a USB if there are any mounted, and then switch to booting from your hard drive into Grub. Grub will not show the USB as an option to boot from. Booting into BIOS or into the One-Time Boot Menu is typically some key like F2, F12, ESC, or anywhere in between. You can search in the manual for your computer to find the key, or you can look online for your model. If you want, you can post information on your computer model here and I can do the research for you.

Comment: Did this answer your question? If it did, please click the check next to it.